# Creating composite key in mnesia

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

How to create a composite key(key with combination of two attributes) in mnesia table.As far as i know is that the first element in record which we use to create mnesia table is primary key.Please expain with simple example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, when use this record

`-record(cuser, {id,login_id,email}).`

to create mnesia table, then the primary key is `id`, but when you change this recode to this:

`-record(cuser, {{id,login_id},email}).`,

then the primary key is `{id,login_id}`.

You can use an ***tuple*** as the primary key.

Comment: I get `bad record field` when compiling this.

Answer (score 0):

@blackmamba's answer did not work for me in OTP 18. I received `bad record field`.

However, from reading http://osdir.com/ml/erlang-questions-programming/1999-10/msg00069.html, I figured out that the following works:

```
-record(state, {idkey, email}).
-record(idkey, {id,login_id}).
```